# Change MVCSiteMapProvider Breadcrumb Depth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I am working on a page that has breadcrumbs set up using the MVCSiteMapProvider and dynamic nodes.  It appears that the GetDynamicNodeCollection method only sets up the immediate parent for the breadcrumbs, and so the breadcrumbs will only display two levels deep.  That is, if you navigate through to the third or fourth level in the hierarchy, say:

> (Home > Level 1 > Level 2 > Level 3 > Level 4)

The first level or two are removed leaving only:

> (Home > Level 3 > Level 4)

I am however, not sure how to update the GetDynamicNodeCollection to allow for the entire breadcrumb trail to be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

Use the [FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#using-filteredsitemapnodevisibilityprovider) to hide the nodes at Level 1 and Level 2 from the SiteMapPath helper.

```
public class MyDynamicNodeProvider
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        // Level 1
        yield return this.MakeInvisibleOnSiteMapPath(
            new DynamicNode() 
            { 
                Key = "Level1Key",
                Title = "Level 1",
                Controller = "Home", 
                Action = "Level1"
            });


        // Level 2
        yield return this.MakeInvisibleOnSiteMapPath(
            new DynamicNode()
            {
                Key = "Level2Key",
                ParentKey = "Level1Key",
                Title = "Level2",
                Controller = "Home",
                Action = "Level2"
            });

        // Level 3
        yield return new DynamicNode()
            {
                Key = "Level3Key",
                ParentKey = "Level2Key",
                Title = "Level3",
                Controller = "Home",
                Action = "Level3"
            };
    }

    private DynamicNode MakeInvisibleOnSiteMapPath(DynamicNode dynamicNode)
    {
        // Setup visibility
        dynamicNode.VisibilityProvider = "MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider";
        dynamicNode.Attributes.Add("visibility", "!SiteMapPathHelper");

        return dynamicNode;
    }
}
```

Note that you can use this in conjunction with [named HTML helpers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#named-html-helper-instances) if you have different visibility requirements in different areas of the site. You could also [build your own visibility provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#creating-a-custom-sitemapnodevisibilityprovider) if your requirements are more advanced.

### Option #2

If your node visibility changes depending on context, you might consider [building your own HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) instead of using built-in the SiteMapPath helper, as it might prove easier to do than using visibility providers. You just need to build an extension method of the MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper class that returns an HTML string. You can get some inspiration for this by reverse-engineering the [SiteMapPathHelper](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/SiteMapPathHelper.cs). I have built a [demo project](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_363) showing how this can be done.